# Why does a cron link respond with a delay when it works more than once?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

There is a php function that does some database and curl operations. I run this function with a url. Right now I'm doing this manually, but I'll tie it to crons in the future.

My problem is this. For example, I have a url like below.

```
domain.com/crons/update_account_data?token=xxx
```

When I enter to this url, the function I direct inside deletes data from the database and processes data from a different service.

I ran the url 3 times at the same time. It immediately deleted the data from the database on the first run. But the second run started after a certain time (for example, after 10 seconds), and the third start after a certain time (for example, after 20 seconds).

What is the reason of this? I want these 3 links that I run at the same time to start operations at the same time.

Comment: I realized that such a problem does not occur when I run a link from a normal tab and a link from an incognito tab. Then I used session_destroy before the link worked but it still didn't fix it.

Comment: Does the script use session variables? If so, the session is locked and only one of the scripts can access it at a time.

Comment: No it doesn't. No session is opened or used during the operation of the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. There is no problem when I enter 4 urls as follows. But I still don't understand why it works delayed if they are all the same.

```
domain.com/crons/update_account_data?token=xxx
domain.com/crons/update_account_data_2?token=xxx
domain.com/crons/update_account_data_3?token=xxx
domain.com/crons/update_account_data_4?token=xxx
```